# line 45 Syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: programming, scripts

Now no matter what I do it just always says that even with a fi it doesnt do that help me debug the code please. also this has 44 lines of text and it says line 45 also the ascii art is just a dog it might look odd though since we are in a smaller area.

```
#!/bin/bash 
clear 

echo "Hello Sir How are you? These are some of my features
date
picture"

read word

if [ $word = picture ]
echo "These are the following pictures I have at my disposel: 
Dog"

if [ $word = date ]

w

fi

read word 

if [ $word = dog ]

fi

echo "
     　__,-;;;＼
　　 　/;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;/ l ＼ヽ |　/＿__
　 　/;;;;;;;;;;;;;;/　　　　　 　 ヽ;;;;;;＼
　　ヽ;;;;;;;;;;;ノ　　　　　　 　　|;;;;;;;;;;;l
　　／￣~~　　　　　　 　 　 |;;;;;;;;;;;;l
　　フ　　○　　　　　　　 　 ＼;;;;;ノ
　,-~~　　　　　　　　　○　　　　ヽ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,､ 　 , , ,
　 ~/　　　　　　●　　　　　 　 ＼,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,V;;;;;;;;;ﾞ,
　 l_,,,　　　　　　　　　　　　　 　>,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;ヽ;;;;;;;,ﾞ
　　　|/l　 /l　,　　　　　　ヽ　|ヽl,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;i- ''
　　　 　 Y　 V ヽlｌﾉ　ﾚ　ヽ）V;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;j
　　　　　 ﾞ,　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　' ' ' ' ' ' ,',,'
　　　　　　ﾞ,　　　　ヽ-,,,,,,,,ﾞ,　　　　ﾞ　　　　　　　ﾞ
　　　　　　 ﾞ,　　　　 ﾞ,　 ,ﾞ ﾞ　　　　ﾞ,ﾞﾞﾞﾞﾞ,　 　　.,ﾞ
　　　　　　　ﾞ,　　　　,ﾞ　 ﾞ,,,ﾞ,　　 　 ﾞ,　 ﾞ, 　 　 ,l
　　　　　　　 ﾞ' ' ' ' ' '　　　 ﾞ' ' ' ' ' '　　 ﾞ' ' ' ' '  "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because bash is looking for the end of the `if` block and can't find it before the end of the file, that's why the error is for line 45.

Now, you have various syntax errors, first of all, an `if` block looks like this:

```
if [ test something ]
then
    do something
fi
```

The keywords `then` and `fi` are needed. Then, you should quote the variables and strings inside the `[ ]` test construct, and you should also be aware that your script will break on spaces and unexpected input.

A working version of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash 
clear 

echo "Hello Sir How are you? These are some of my features
date
picture"

read word

if [ "$word" = "picture" ]
then
echo "These are the following pictures I have at my disposel: 
Dog"
fi


if [ "$word" = "date" ]
then
    w
fi

read word

if [ "$word" = "dog" ]
then
echo "
     　__,-;;;＼
　　 　/;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;/ l ＼ヽ |　/＿__
　 　/;;;;;;;;;;;;;;/　　　　　 　 ヽ;;;;;;＼
　　ヽ;;;;;;;;;;;ノ　　　　　　 　　|;;;;;;;;;;;l
　　／￣~~　　　　　　 　 　 |;;;;;;;;;;;;l
　　フ　　○　　　　　　　 　 ＼;;;;;ノ
　,-~~　　　　　　　　　○　　　　ヽ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,､ 　 , , ,
　 ~/　　　　　　●　　　　　 　 ＼,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,V;;;;;;;;;ﾞ,
　 l_,,,　　　　　　　　　　　　　 　>,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;ヽ;;;;;;;,ﾞ
　　　|/l　 /l　,　　　　　　ヽ　|ヽl,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;i- ''
　　　 　 Y　 V ヽlｌﾉ　ﾚ　ヽ）V;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;j
　　　　　 ﾞ,　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　' ' ' ' ' ' ,',,'
　　　　　　ﾞ,　　　　ヽ-,,,,,,,,ﾞ,　　　　ﾞ　　　　　　　ﾞ
　　　　　　 ﾞ,　　　　 ﾞ,　 ,ﾞ ﾞ　　　　ﾞ,ﾞﾞﾞﾞﾞ,　 　　.,ﾞ
　　　　　　　ﾞ,　　　　,ﾞ　 ﾞ,,,ﾞ,　　 　 ﾞ,　 ﾞ, 　 　 ,l
　　　　　　　 ﾞ' ' ' ' ' '　　　 ﾞ' ' ' ' ' '　　 ﾞ' ' ' ' '  " 
fi
```

Note that you still have design problems, this is not a well written script, apart from not handling any errors, you also don't exit if any of the choices are entered which means that no matter what I do, I will eventually get to the dog printing. Even if I enter `date`, you might want to add some `exit` calls in there.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `fi` here, and I cleaned it up a little (e.g. disposal) -

```
if [ "$word" = "picture" ]; then
  echo "These are the following pictures I have at my disposal: Dog"
fi # <-- Right there.
```